# I want to get the attribute of point, It reports error C3867: 'point::output_x': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to implement the openGL to draw the fixed points based on the coordinate value, such as x and y.

Here is my code:
Firstly, I created point class and some functions:

***Point.h***

```
#pragma once
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

class point {
private:
    int name;
    double x;
    double y;


public:
    point();
    point(int name, double x, double y);
    ~point();
    void print_coordinate_point();
    double output_x();
    double output_y();

};
```

***Point.cpp***

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Point.h"

point::point() {
    name = 0;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

point::point(int new_name, double x_cp, double y_cp) {
    name = new_name;
    x = x_cp;
    y = y_cp;
}


point::~point() {

}


void point::print_coordinate_point() {
    std::cout << "the point of " << name << " , and its coordinate is (" << x << "," << y << "). \n";
}

double point::output_x() {
    return x;
}

double point::output_y() {
    return y;
}
```

Secondly, I created the main.cpp. It helps me handle the csv problem and create the vector to store the points.
And the ***main.cpp*** like this:

```
#define FREEGLUT_STATIC
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include "math.h";
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>
#include <vector>
#include "Point.h"



/*csv*/
int noodrows();
int noodcols();
using namespace std;
string** gen_Matrix(int rows, int cols);
void printMatrix(string** matrix, int rows, int cols);
void InputMatrix(string** matrix, int rows, int cols);
/*points*/
void createPoints(vector<point> new_vector, string** matrix, int rows, int cols);
/*openGL*/
void part1_define_to_OpenGL_1();

//parameter
string location = "D:\\Final-Year-Project-master\\FYP\\points_matrix.csv";
vector<point> point_vector;



void main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int rows, cols;
    rows = noodrows();
    cols = noodcols();
    cout << "no of rows are: " << rows << "\t";
    cout << "no of cols are: " << cols << "\t"<<endl;
    string** matrix = gen_Matrix(rows, cols);
    InputMatrix(matrix, rows, cols);
    //printMatrix(matrix, rows, cols);

    /*Create the vector of points*/
    vector<point> new_vector(rows);
    point_vector = new_vector;
    createPoints(new_vector, matrix, rows, cols);


    /*opengl-display*/
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitWindowSize(600, 400);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);


    glutCreateWindow("Graphics Perimitives");

    glutDisplayFunc(part1_define_to_OpenGL_1);
    glutMainLoop();




}

void part1_define_to_OpenGL_1() {
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    //TASK 2        
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-120, 120, -120, 120);

    //TASK 4
    glPointSize(10.0);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
    int length = point_vector.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2f(point_vector[i].output_x, point_vector[i].output_y);
        glEnd();
    }


    glFlush();



}



int noodcols() {

    //get the colume for the csv.
    ifstream file3(location);
    string data;
    int counter = 0;
    getline(file3, data);
    stringstream sstream(data);
    while (!sstream.eof()) {
        getline(sstream, data, ',');
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;


}





int noodrows() {
    //get the row for the csv
    ifstream file2(location);
    if (!file2.is_open()) {
        cout << "cannot open the file" << endl;

    }

    string data;
    int counter = 0;


    while (getline(file2, data)) {
        //cout << data << endl;
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}


string** gen_Matrix(int rows, int cols) {
    //generate the empty matrix
    string** matrix = new string * [rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        matrix[i] = new string[cols];
    }
    return matrix;
}

void printMatrix(string** matrix, int rows, int cols) {
    //print the result of matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        cout << "the line of: " << i<<endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}


void createPoints(vector<point> new_vector,string** matrix,int rows,int cols) {

    double x;
    double y;


    for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 2; ++col) {
            if (col == 0) {
                string str1 = matrix[row][col];
                x = atof(const_cast<const char*>(str1.c_str()));   //string to double
            }
            else {
                string str2 = matrix[row][col];
                y = atof(const_cast<const char*>(str2.c_str()));   //string to double
            }



        }
        point new_point(row, x, y);
        new_point.print_coordinate_point();
        new_vector[row] = new_point;



    }

}




void InputMatrix(string** matrix, int rows, int cols) {
    ifstream file(location);
    stringstream buffer;
    buffer << file.rdbuf();
    string data;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            if (j == cols - 1) {
                getline(buffer, data, '\n');
                matrix[i][j] = data;
                j++;
                continue;
            }
            else {
                getline(buffer, data, ',');
                matrix[i][j] = data;
            }

        }
    }


}
```

I have already stored the data to the points from csv.file. Also the points are stored in the ***vector: point_vector*** .

When I want to use member function output_x to get the value of x, 
 `glVertex2f(point_vector[i].output_x, point_vector[i].output_y);`

It reports error like this:

```
1>C:\Users\Tyler.Tuo\source\repos\csv\csv\points_matrix_csv.cpp(82,38): error C3867: 'point::output_x': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
1>C:\Users\Tyler.Tuo\source\repos\csv\csv\points_matrix_csv.cpp(82,64): error C3867: 'point::output_y': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

Actually, the problem has nothing to do with opengl but the method to visit the attributes of class.

How to fix this problem, Did it means that we must use the points to visit the attributes of x,y in points?

Comment: Looks like you want to call a function. You forgot the `()`.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks :), I forget the synatx of function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line in `part1_define_to_OpenGL_1`:

```
glVertex2f(point_vector[i].output_x, point_vector[i].output_y);
```

You're missing the parenthesis to call the functions `output_x` and `output_y`.